Is it possible to define a C++ function where one parameter is passed via the EAX register?
An old game doesn't work on my PC and I want to fix it. A function of the game might cause the problem. So I decided to hook this function with Detours. The following code is generated by IDA. mbstowcs is the function I want to hook.
.text:0043A9D4 ; int __fastcall mbstowcs(LPWSTR lpWideCharStr, LPCSTR lpMultiByteStr)
.text:0043A9D4 mbstowcs        proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_408D58+39↑p
.text:0043A9D4                                         ; sub_408D58+65↑p ...
.text:0043A9D4
.text:0043A9D4 cchWideChar     = dword ptr -14h
.text:0043A9D4
.text:0043A9D4                 push    ebx
.text:0043A9D5                 push    esi
.text:0043A9D6                 push    edi
.text:0043A9D7                 push    ebp
.text:0043A9D8                 push    ecx
.text:0043A9D9                 mov     [esp+14h+cchWideChar], ecx
.text:0043A9DC                 mov     esi, edx
.text:0043A9DE                 mov     edi, eax
.text:0043A9E0                 test    edi, edi
.text:0043A9E2                 jz      short loc_43A9F1
.text:0043A9E4                 cmp     [esp+14h+cchWideChar], 0
.text:0043A9E8                 jnz     short loc_43A9F1
.text:0043A9EA                 xor     eax, eax
.text:0043A9EC                 jmp     loc_43AA77
.text:0043A9F1 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:0043A9F1
.text:0043A9F1 loc_43A9F1:                             ; CODE XREF: mbstowcs+E↑j
.text:0043A9F1                                         ; mbstowcs+14↑j
.text:0043A9F1                 test    edi, edi
.text:0043A9F3                 jz      short loc_43AA5D
.text:0043A9F5                 mov     ebx, [esp+14h+cchWideChar]
.text:0043A9F8                 push    ebx             ; cchWideChar
.text:0043A9F9                 push    edi             ; lpWideCharStr
.text:0043A9FA                 push    0FFFFFFFFh      ; cbMultiByte
.text:0043A9FC                 push    esi             ; lpMultiByteStr
.text:0043A9FD                 push    9               ; dwFlags
.text:0043A9FF                 push    0               ; CodePage
.text:0043AA01                 call    MultiByteToWideChar
.text:0043AA06                 test    eax, eax
.text:0043AA08                 jz      short loc_43AA0D
.text:0043AA0A                 dec     eax
.text:0043AA0B                 jmp     short loc_43AA77

At line .text:0043A9DE, a parameter seems to be passed via the EAX register. As far as I know, the target function and detour function must have same calling convention. The problem is, I don't know what calling convention requires that parameter be passed via EAX.
I'm using MSVC 19.40.
I tried to use the default and fastcall calling conventions, but no parameters are passed via EAX.
How to hook this function? How to define a function whose parameter is passed through EAX?

Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions, matching calling convention are optlink, borland register, watcom register, topspeed, clarion and JPI. I don't think MSVC provides native support for any, so you will have to write a wrapper using assembly.

GCC's 32-bit __attribute__((regparm((3))) convention passes the first arg in EAX, like the Borland convention.  MSVC probably doesn't support it, but if you can use clang-cl or GCC, they do support a calling convention that passes args in regs starting with EAX.  But yes, your function does seem to be reading EAX, presumably as a function arg.

This code incorrectly declares mbstowcs() as taking 2 parameters, but the code is looking for 3 parameters in EAX, EDX, and ECX, respectively. The real declaration of mbstowcs() is size_t mbstowcs(wchar_t *wcstr, const char *mbstr, size_t count); In MSVC, the only 32bit conventions that use these registers for parameters are __fastcall and __vectorcall , but they don't use them in this order. And the 64bit convention uses registers for parameters but not these ones.  So, this makes me think this code is a custom asm function that your decompiler misidentified as mbstowcs().

@RemyLebeau: 32-bit __fastcall and __vectorcall don't use EAX at all for arg-passing, only as a return value.

@PeterCordes true, but they do use EDX and ECX. I'm betting this game wasn't written in MSVC to begin with.

@ChayimFriedman only optlink and Borland register would be a match for this code. The others you mention use EBX for one of their parameters, but this code does not use EBX for any parameter.

@RemyLebeau: Yup, so that rules out either of those MSVC conventions.  As you say, optlink and Borland register / GCC regparm(3) are the only fully matching conventions (I actually didn't check that no others matched, but those do).  Agreed that MSVC probably doesn't support them, which would make it impossible to generate the desired asm using MSVC; you'd need to hand-write in asm or use a different compiler for at least one function.

It works. I defined a function like this:
size_t __attribute__((regparm(3))) better_mbstowcs(wchar_t* pwcs, const char* s, size_t n)

and compiled it with clang-cl. IDA output:
.text:10001060                 public better_mbstowcs
.text:10001060 better_mbstowcs proc near               ; DATA XREF: DllMain(x,x,x)+3C↓o
.text:10001060                                         ; DllMain(x,x,x)+69↓o ...
.text:10001060                 push    esi
.text:10001061                 test    eax, eax
.text:10001063                 jz      short loc_1000106B
.text:10001065                 xor     esi, esi
.text:10001067                 test    ecx, ecx
.text:10001069                 jz      short loc_10001088
.text:1000106B
.text:1000106B loc_1000106B:                           ; CODE XREF: better_mbstowcs+3↑j
.text:1000106B                 test    eax, eax
.text:1000106D                 cmovz   ecx, eax
.text:10001070                 push    ecx             ; cchWideChar
.text:10001071                 push    eax             ; lpWideCharStr
.text:10001072                 push    0FFFFFFFFh      ; cbMultiByte
.text:10001074                 push    edx             ; lpMultiByteStr
.text:10001075                 push    0               ; dwFlags
.text:10001077                 push    0               ; CodePage
.text:10001079                 call    ds:MultiByteToWideChar

It looks good.
